# How to check if the result of std::frexp is specified under the current compiler?

Tags: c++, floating-point, unspecified-behavior

[`std::frexp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/frexp) is a function that removes exponent from a floating point variable and puts it into a variable `exp` of type `int`. It uses `int` regardless of how many bits the exponent really needs and according to the linked page:

> If the value to be stored in `*exp` is outside the range of `int`, the behavior is unspecified.

So, how do I check whether "`*exp` is outside the range of `int`"?

I am thinking about adding a `static_assert` to my code that compares [`FLT_MIN_EXP` & `FLT_MAX_EXP`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat) to [`INT_MIN` & `INT_MAX`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits).
However, I'm afraid of making an off-by-one error because I don't fully comprehend descriptions of these constants.

`FLT_MIN_EXP`:

> minimum negative integer such that FLT_RADIX raised by power one less than that integer is a normalized `float`...

`FLT_MAX_EXP`:

> maximum positive integer such that FLT_RADIX raised by power one less than that integer is a representable finite `float`...

(I already have `static_assert(FLT_RADIX == 2);` in the code so radix equal to 10 is not a concern in my case.)

Comment: Even [quad-precision floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format) have only 15 bits of exponent, so I wouldn't check this at all.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I assume this remark about unspecified behavior hasn't come from nothing. For example: [octuple-preciion floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octuple-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: Okay, and still just 19 bits of exponent? While `int` is most often 32 bits. *"hasn't come from nothing"* It probably has. It's an interesting question by itself, but not very practical.

Comment: Could an equivalent question be, "How do I know the number of exponent bits in my `float`, `double`, and `long double` types?"

Comment: I sympathize with the desire to future proof. Can you add a unit test that tests at runtime if you get the correct (or sane) results for non-zero floating point types of largest and smallest magnitude?

Comment: @JohnFilleau I don't think it is exactly the same. I don't think the format in which the exponent is stored in the floating point is two's complement. (I may be wrong. This is a complicated topic.)

Comment: @PiotrSiupa acknowledged that it's a complicated topic.

Comment: @JohnFilleau Define "correct results". Generally, I would prefer compile-time check. I'm trying to follow the zero-unnecessary-overhead route.

Comment: What do you want to do if this static assertion fails? Re-visit the problem?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat -- where it probably comes from is the collision between 16-bit `int` and various forms of floating-point types back in the olden days, before IEEE-754.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I would declare that this specific compiler is stupid and I don't support it since the function I need doesn't work.

Comment: You know, it occurs to me you could just have a static check to make sure `sizeof(int) >= 32`. That will cover the majority of your platforms and you can revisit when it's not true (working on an embedded system, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assertion 1: This operation *usually works fine*, and you don't need to worry about anything.

Assertion 2: For peace of mind, if there's every a system where this doesn't work, we want to know about it. We'll revisit a solution when we find one of those systems.

Assertion 3: The largest and smallest exponents returned from `std::frexp` can be represented by the system's `int` type if the operation is *reversible*.

You reverse `std::frexp` by its complement [`std::ldexp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ldexp).

Note that if `int` cannot hold a floating point's exponent, the result is *not undefined* (it's merely unspecified), so we can rely on the test being well formed.

#### Write a unit test that tests if this is reversible

```
TEST_CASE("The largest exponent returned by std::frexp can be represented by int") {
    long double largest_ld = std::numeric_limits<long double>::max();

    int exponent;
    long double fraction = std::frexp(largest_ld, &exponent);

    errno = 0;
    REQUIRE(std::ldexp(fraction, exponent) == largest_ld);
    REQUIRE(errno == 0); // just in case?
}

TEST_CASE("The smallest exponent returned by std::frexp can be represented by int") {
    long double smallest_ld = std::numeric_limits<long double>::min();

    int exponent;
    long double fraction = std::frexp(smallest_ld, &exponent);

    errno = 0;
    REQUIRE(std::ldexp(fraction, exponent) == smallest_ld);
    REQUIRE(errno == 0); // just in case?
}
```

#### Can you do better with compile time checks?

Probably, but I'm having trouble understanding the same part of the language you were having trouble with, so I'm optimizing developer speed over compile time checks.

As a first order approximation, may I suggest:

```
static_assert(sizeof(int) >= 32);
static_assert(std::numeric_limits<long double>::is_eec559);
```

And of course, revisit when you hit a platform where this isn't true.

Comment: I think units test can be kinda considered static assertions if they are part of the build-chain. Good idea!